# Load up workspace state on open vs code extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, initialization, state, vscode-extensions

I've been working on a vs code extension to make a button in the status bar that will run a script in the terminal. I have saved the state of the buttons and the custom user commands in context.workspaceState.

However, it only seems to load up when I trigger the command from the command palette and not from the initial load.

For example, I will open a new project that I had previously created a button on, and in the status bar it would not show. Then I will go to `add button` in the command palette, exit out of it, then the buttons in the status bar will show.

Do you know why this is happening?

extension.ts

```js
import { commands, ExtensionContext } from 'vscode'
import {
  addButtonScript,
  deleteButtonScript,
  loadInitialState,
} from './buttonScripts'
import { resetStateScript, viewStateScript } from './debuggingHelpers'

export interface WorkspaceState {
  name: string
  command: string
}

export async function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
  await loadInitialState(context)

  const deleteButton = commands.registerCommand('extension.deleteButton', () =>
    deleteButtonScript(context)
  )
  const addButton = commands.registerCommand('extension.addButton', () =>
    addButtonScript(context)
  )
  //debugging scripts
  const viewState = commands.registerCommand('extension.viewState', () =>
    viewStateScript(context)
  )
  const resetState = commands.registerCommand('extension.resetState', () =>
    resetStateScript(context)
  )

  context.subscriptions.push(addButton, deleteButton, viewState, resetState)
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

butonScripts.ts

```js
import { window, ExtensionContext, commands } from 'vscode'
import { resetStateScript } from './debuggingHelpers'
import { WorkspaceState } from './extension'
import {
  createButton,
  addSingleObjectToState,
  getState,
  updateState,
} from './utilities'

export async function loadInitialState(context: ExtensionContext) {
  const initialState = await getState(context)
  // Load button state(s) is there is any
  if (!!initialState && initialState !== '') {
    const workspaceState: WorkspaceState[] = await JSON.parse(initialState!)
    workspaceState.forEach(({ name, command }) => createButton(name, command))
}

export async function addButtonScript(context: ExtensionContext) {
  const command = await window.showInputBox({
    prompt: 'Add in the script command you want to run in the terminal',
  })
  if (!command) return window.showErrorMessage('No command provided')

  const name = await nameInput()
  if (!name) return

  await createButton(name!, command!)
  await addSingleObjectToState({ context, name, command })
  return
}

export async function deleteButtonScript(context: ExtensionContext) {
  const currentState = await getState(context)

  if (!currentState || currentState === '[]') {
    window.showErrorMessage('No buttons to delete')
    return
  }
  const buttonNamesParsed: WorkspaceState[] = JSON.parse(currentState!)
  const buttonNames = buttonNamesParsed.map(({ name }) => name)

  const buttonSelection = await window.showQuickPick(
    [...buttonNames, `Delete all`],
    { title: 'Choose a button to delete. Warning: this will reload the window' }
  )
  if (!buttonSelection) return window.showErrorMessage('No button selected')
  if (buttonSelection === 'Delete all') resetStateScript(context)
  if (buttonSelection !== 'Delete all') {
    const newState = buttonNamesParsed.filter(
      ({ name }) => name !== buttonSelection
    )
    await updateState(context, newState)
  }
  commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.reloadWindow')
  return
}

async function nameInput() {
  const input = await window.showInputBox({
    prompt: 'Add the name of the button (max 5 characters)',
  })

  if (!input) {
    window.showErrorMessage('No name provided')
    return
  }
  if (input.length! > 5) {
    window.showErrorMessage('Name is too long')
    nameInput()
  }
  if (input.length < 6) return input
  return
}
```

Full repo is here if you need it - https://github.com/puyanwei/quick-scripts-v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `package.json`:

```
  "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:extension.addButton",
    "onCommand:extension.deleteButton"
  ],
```

So your extension only activates on triggering either of those commands.

Try this instead:

```
 "activationEvents": [
  "onStartupFinished"
 ],
```

so that your extension is activated once vscode startup is complete.  You may find through intellisense other `activationEvents` that also work to activate your extension earlier.